# какие программы есть для миониторинга БД на MySQl?

Tags: mysql, администрирование

посоветуйте пожалуйста простые программы для мониторинга БДшки, самые простенькие и не геморные, пробовал PRTG Network c ее сенсорами и всякой хренью, не разобрался, есть что-нибудь попроще ? Нужно отслеживать запросы, самые популярные, самые долгие и тп и тд...

Comment: Заббикс, из коробки умеет в MySQL :) но на старте вам он будет не проще чем prtg

Comment: на Windows server 12 встанет?

Comment: Зависит от рук установщика xD